# How to remove rows with duplicate elements in a matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, duplicates

I seek to use the `unique` function or whatever to eliminate rows with duplicate pairs in  column 1 and 2. In other words, two or more rows having the same elements in 1st two columns, irrespective of the order, are considered duplicates and needed to be removed.

For example, given the following matrix:

```
A =  3     3     3
     3     2     3
     3     2     3
     1     3     3
     3     1     2
```

I would like to get this result:

```
A =  3     3     3
     3     2     3
     1     3     3
```

How to do this?

Comment: @SardarUsama  because 1 3 and 3 1 it's a dublicate value also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sort](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) the first two columns to make the duplicates like `[1 3]` and `[3 1]` alike. Then use [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) with the `rows` and `stable` flags to find the subscripts of unique rows and in the original order respectively. Now use these row subscripts to index the desired rows.

```
[~, idx] = unique(sort(A(:,1:2),2),'rows','stable');
A = A(idx,:);
```